# How to set the BACK button on the black bar menu on the bottom of android screen to turn my app off?

Tags: android, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins, hybrid

I made a hybrid app (game) which contains many html files. And when I play and click on this button [image]
my app turns to previous page. Now should I set this button to turn my app off (and if yes how?) or maybe you have a better idea?

Comment: do you ever want to come back to your previous page? if not just, clearing the backstack should work

Comment: you are kinda breaking the android platforms design guidelines for what the user can expect from native behaviours. look into calling the Activity finish() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html#backbutton, documentation for tapping Back button and triggering the event.

May I suggest you just disable the back button action - do not close the app, do not close back. To go back or turn off the app, you should have an action on your screen, and the confirmation prompt.